# script-src постоянно запрещает скрипты

Tags: javascript, html, chrome-extension

Хочу сделать расширение для Chrome. Но когда я нажимаю какую-либо кнопку, выводится ошибка директивы script-src. Уже пробовал добавлять meta теги, но это не сработало.
Как решить эту ошибку?

Comment: А кто будет делать [mcve]?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.